# extracting geographic location from NOAA NARR grib

Tags: data, geolocation, grib, noaa

I've downloaded a NOAA NARR grib file that I want to extract the wind component as well as the geographic location.  I'm able to extract the wind component from the grib but I can't seem to find any indication that there's a specific latitude/longitude value for each data point.  Ultimately I want to extract the data and load it into a relational database with time,location,wind_data.  The grib file I'm using can be found here.

http://nomads.ncdc.noaa.gov/data/narr/201410/20141001/narr-a_221_20141001_0000_000.grb

Answer (score 2):

You can translate the first (or any other) band of the grib raster to XYZ format using:

```
gdal_translate -b 1 -of "XYZ" narr-a.gsb narr-a.xyz
```

This gives you the coordinates in the lcc projection used.

Then you can load this file as delimited text into QGIS, using `field_1` as X and `field_2` as Y coordinate, and the following custom CRS (derived from what gdalinfo reports on the grb):

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=50 +lat_2=50 +lat_0=50 +lon_0=-107 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371200 +b=6371200 +units=m +no_defs
```

This point layer can easily be reprojected to WGS84, and the WGS84 coordinates added to the attribute table.

Alternatively to QGIS, the reprojection should also be possible using pure GDAL.